# Play a sound from bytearray in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, audio

I am recording sound using Microphone class. After completing the record, I am getting a byte array.

Now I want to use this byte array and play the sound. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d1d.html)

In short, make the microphone generate 44.1 kHz samples (mono), duplicate them in your own sample data procedure, and store them in your `Sound` object. 44kHz are mandatory to not have your sound pitched, as it's always played back as 44.1kHz sound. The resampling is to make mono sound into stereo sound, as you can't have mono sounds in Flash.